# delphi XML documentation for generic classes

Tags: delphi, generics, xml-documentation

So I wanted to document my class' methods so it would work with Help Insight. I then discovered XML documentation so I tried to use it but it didn't work for me for whatever reason.

I then tried to make some easier project rather than adding this documentation  to an existing one and it worked well so by experimenting I discover that it's because my class is generic. Does anyone know how to solve it? I mean.. it's not THAT important but it would be nice to have code documented with working Help Insight...

I add a code of a example project I've made

```
interface
  type
   whatever = class
     public
     /// <summary> Remoified item from the collection </summary>
     /// <param name="Item">The item  remove </param>
     /// <param name="Collection"> item </param>
     /// <remarks> If parameter "Item" an exception is raised.
     /// <see cref="EArgumentNilException"/> </remarks>
     /// <returns> False is returned. </returns>
     function test(Item: Pointer; Collection: Pointer): Boolean;
   end;

   whatever<e> = class
     public
     /// <summary> from the collection </summary>
     /// <param name="Item">Te </param>
     /// <param name="Collection"> item </param>
     /// <remarks> an exception is raised.
     /// <see cref="EArgumentNilException"/> </remarks>
     /// <returns> False . </returns>
     function test(Item: Pointer; Collection: Pointer): Boolean;
   end;

  /// <summary> Removes the specified item from the collection </summary>
  /// <param name="Item">The item to remove </param>

  /// <param name="Collection">The group containing the item </param>
  /// <remarks> If parameter "Item" is null, an exception is raised.
  /// <see cref="EArgumentNilException"/> </remarks>
  /// <returns>True if the specified item is successfully removed;
  /// otherwise False is returned. </returns>
  function test(Item: Pointer; Collection: Pointer): Boolean;
implementation
...
```

As you can see I even used an example annotation from

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/XML_Documentation_Comments

It works well for both "whatever" class and unit method but it desn't work for

```
whatever<e> = class
```

I'm testing it from other unit:

```
var
we:whatever;
wee:whatever<integer>;
begin
  try
    test();
    we.test();
    wee.test();
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

I know this wouldn't compile but that's beside a point.
Insight help shows requested documentation on test(); and we.test(); but on wee.test it just shows standart "Declared in ..."

Btw. within a class where methods are defined insight help works well (by that I mean that if I hover with mouse over

```
fuction whatever<E>.test(Item, Collection : Pointer) : boolean;
```

it will show me requested documentation but it won't work from outside.

I also tried to add documetation for types but that doesn't help me.
I don't want any code workarounds where I would have to add methods just to make this work (but feel free to post them as they could help others) I'm just wondering if I'm doing something wrong or I have to set something or if it just doesn't work with generic classes.

Edit1: I suspect that RAD studio just doesn't see it as a same class when you define it with a type (what is really weird as that is how you use generics.. I guess).

Also excuse me for weird formatting I fing it just won't let me use > and < in normal text as it's used for links

RAD Studio 10.1 Berlin update 2 - just figured out it could help